# Spec for GPAC's DashCast configuration?

Tags: mpeg

According to [DashCast](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/dashcast/), we should provide a configuration file of several entries. The document demos some options:

```
[v1] 
type=video 
width=1280 
height=720 
bitrate=800000 
[v2]
type=video 
width=640 
height=360 
bitrate=400000 
[a1]
type=audio
bitrate=128000
[a2]
type=audio
bitrate=256000
```

For my first run of DashCash, the configuration file would be automatically generated if it is not existing. Here is the autogenerated one:

```
[v1]
type=video
bitrate=2000000
framerate=24
width=1920
height=1080
crop_x=0
crop_y=0
codec=libx264

[a1]
type=audio
bitrate=192000
samplerate=44100
channels=2
codec=aac
```

I'm wondering where I can get a spec of options for this configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available on the page you linked to directly.  Look under the Configuration Files section.

Relevant details from the page:

A file "-conf" file.

```
[ID]        # The ID of the representation
type=T      # T can be "audio" or "video"
width=W     # if type is "video", 
            # W is the width of the representation
height=H    # if type is "video", 
            # H is the height of the representation
bitrate=B   # B is the bitrate (bps) of "video" or "audio"
```

And a "-switch-source" file.

```
[ID]         # The ID of the source identification.
type=T       # T can be "video"
start=ST     # ST is the start time YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
end=ET       # ET is the end time YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
source=S     # S is the address of the source
```

Additionally, from looking in the source itself, the configuration file is read in the cmd_data.c file starting on line 160 or so (depending on rev) in the dc_read_configuration method.

For the conf file, video type can have codec, framerate, crop_x, crop_y and custom.  Audio types can have codec, samplerate, channels and custom.

Custom appears to push the value assigned directly in to the libav codec.

For the Switch source file, the type appears to actually be able to be video or audio.  Both only have the listed 4 options.

Comment: I doubt it is the full spec. According to my test, the automatically generated configuration would use more options than the one in the doc. I just updated my question with another sample.

Comment: @Drake - hmm, I don't know then, I couldn't find any further documentation available when I looked.  I suppose you probably had the same problem.  I was able to dig up a little bit more detail from reading the source code itself.

Comment: Let's wait and see if there would be more complete spec then.